# How to put title automatically on a series of generated plots with 'apply'

Tags: r, function, plot, apply

I'm switching from SPSS to R for data analysis and I'm trying to write a scrpit I could use for most future analyses. To check normality, I would like to plot histograms, QQ plots and descpriptives of every continuous variable.
 For this, I would like R to genereate qqplots of all continuous variables in the dataset with the variable as title.
 I managed to do so by first selecting all numerical variables and storing them as data.
 Next I tried to use apply to generate a qqplot of all columns. I managed to do so, but unfortunately I did not succeed to get the right title even after strugling and trying for more than one day. I need to know how to code to automatically take the variables (x) name as title. Does anyone know how to solve this?

This is wat I did and doesn't work at all:

```
apply(data.numerical, 2, function(x) {ggqqplot(x, title=colnames(data.numerical)[x])})
```

Thanks in advance!

Jeroen

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, and to R! First I'll provide a solution, with some tips on asking questions on Stack Overflow in the future. Then I'll provide an explanation of why your attempt didn't work.

### Solution

So here's how I'd do it, which in some ways is not *that* different from what you tried:

```r
## Specify non-base packages needed
library(ggpubr)
## Generate example data
set.seed(123)
data.numerical <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100))
## Make QQ plot for each column with the column's name as the title
sapply(names(data.numerical), function(x) {
    print(ggqqplot(data = data.numerical, x = x, title = x))
})
## Or, equivalently
plots <- lapply(names(data.numerical), function(x) {
    ggqqplot(data = data.numerical, x = x, title = x)
})
plots[[1]]
plots[[2]]
```

Here's the results; you can see the plots are appropriately named:

[image]

[image]

Notice the things I put in that code *before* the plotting code, specifying the packages I was using and giving an easy way for others to reproduce my data. When asking questions in the future, please provide these things; they give us what we call a minimal reproducible example, which helps us help you.

### So why didn't my attempt work?

If we look at `help("ggqqplot")`, we'll see the function expects the `data` to be specified as well as the column `x` to be plotted. So, rather than `apply()`ing over the columns, I `sapply()` over the names to specify `x` that way. This also helps with the `title` argument; since I'm `sapply()`ing over the names, I can provide them directly to the `title` argument.

Most importantly `colnames(data.numerical)[x]` is not doing what I think you think it's doing. In the context of your attempt, `x` is **not** a column index, but a *whole column of your data frame*. So, it's not subsetting the column names like how you were probably expecting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and clear explanation! Why is the `print` function needed in this case?

Comment: For functions such as `ggqqplot()`, they return a `ggplot` object. The way to actually plot such an object is with a `print()` statement, or equivalently just typing the name bound to the object in the console. I'll edit to include this other way as well.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! To reinforce some points from @duckmayer.

1. Always tell us more about your data
2. Start with the attitude someone has had your problem and there's a package for that.  Including ones for `expss` users (hint, hint).  Don't reinvent wheels.

Since I happen to have [written a function](https://ibecav.github.io/CGPfunctions/reference/SeeDist.html) to inspect univariate distros I'll use it.  No claim it's the best but here it is.  In the real case you'll find dplyr::select_if makes it easy to choose just numeric variables from your dataset

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(CGPfunctions)

playdata <- mtcars %>% select(hp, mpg, qsec)
titlevar <- names(playdata)
playdata %>% purrr::map2(.y = titlevar, ~ SeeDist(.x, whatplots = "d", title = .y))
#> Warning: There are 7 modal values displaying just the first 3
```

[image][image][image]

```
#> $hp
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> .x
#> 
#>   length       n    NAs  unique      0s    mean  meanCI'
#>       32      32      0      22       0  146.69  121.97
#>           100.0%   0.0%            0.0%          171.41
#>                                                        
#>      .05     .10    .25  median     .75     .90     .95
#>    63.65   66.00  96.50  123.00  180.00  243.50  253.55
#>                                                        
#>    range      sd  vcoef     mad     IQR    skew    kurt
#>   283.00   68.56   0.47   77.10   83.50    0.73   -0.14
#>                                                        
#> lowest : 52.00, 62.00, 65.00, 66.00 (2), 91.00
#> highest: 215.00, 230.00, 245.00 (2), 264.00, 335.00
#> 
#> ' 95%-CI (classic)
#> 
#> 
#> $mpg
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> .x
#> 
#>   length       n    NAs  unique     0s   mean  meanCI'
#>       32      32      0      25      0  20.09   17.92
#>           100.0%   0.0%           0.0%          22.26
#>                                                      
#>      .05     .10    .25  median    .75    .90     .95
#>    12.00   14.34  15.43   19.20  22.80  30.09   31.30
#>                                                      
#>    range      sd  vcoef     mad    IQR   skew    kurt
#>    23.50    6.03   0.30    5.41   7.38   0.61   -0.37
#>                                                      
#> lowest : 10.40 (2), 13.30, 14.30, 14.70, 15.00
#> highest: 26.00, 27.30, 30.40 (2), 32.40, 33.90
#> 
#> ' 95%-CI (classic)
#> 
#> 
#> $qsec
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> .x
#> 
#>   length       n    NAs  unique     0s   mean  meanCI'
#>       32      32      0      30      0  17.85   17.20
#>           100.0%   0.0%           0.0%          18.49
#>                                                      
#>      .05     .10    .25  median    .75    .90     .95
#>    15.05   15.53  16.89   17.71  18.90  19.99   20.10
#>                                                      
#>    range      sd  vcoef     mad    IQR   skew    kurt
#>     8.40    1.79   0.10    1.42   2.01   0.37    0.34
#>                                                      
#> lowest : 14.50, 14.60, 15.41, 15.50, 15.84
#> highest: 19.90, 20.00, 20.01, 20.22, 22.90
#> 
#> ' 95%-CI (classic)
```

Comment: just wondering are you using an older version of `CGPfunctions` here? I've just installed it and `title` is missing from the help `?SeeDist` section whereas its not in the link you gave. When I run the above code I get `Error in SeeDist(.x, whatplots = "d", title = .y) : 
  unused argument (title = .y)` thanks

Comment: Ugh sorry I'm using a newer version where I added a bunch of functionality `devtools::install_github("ibecav/CGPfunctions", build_vignettes = TRUE)`